# I get this Error: Cannot find module './lib/async' Require stack:.How to resolve this error?

Tags: reactjs

Till yesterday,my project was running smoothly with no bugs.
But today I started getting this error:

Error: Cannot find module './lib/async'

```
Require stack:
- D:\cg\cg-frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\resolve\index.js
- D:\cg\cg-frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\utils\verifyTypeScriptSetup.js
- D:\cg\cg-frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\cg\cg-frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\resolve\index.js:1:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\cg\\cg-frontend\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\node_modules\\resolve\\index.js',
    'D:\\cg\\cg-frontend\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\utils\\verifyTypeScriptSetup.js',
    'D:\\cg\\cg-frontend\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: have you tried deleting `node_modules` folder and installing dependencies again. Seems like it's complaining about the absence of async module.

Comment: I just tried to uninstall a dependency but I didn't delete node_modules folder.

Comment: maybe delete node_modules folder and install all dependencies again, lets see if error persists and if its the same error.

Comment: ok.its working now.Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the best approach in these instances is to delete `node_modules` folder and re-install all dependencies again.